# Performance Implication of Creating New TCP Connection Per Message

Tags: performance, sockets, networking, service, tcp

In the past, our server application was designed so that a client creates one TCP connection, keeps this connection established indefinitely and sends messages when needed.  These messages may come in high volume bursts or with longer idle periods in between.  We are switching to a different connection protocol now, where the client will create a new connection per message and then disconnect after sending.

I have a few questions:

1. I know there is some overhead for the 3-shake handshake to establish the connection.  But is this overhead significant (cpu, memory, bandwidth, etc.)?
2. Is there any difference between the latency of message being transferred for an established TCP connection that has been idle for minutes vs. creating a new connection and sending the message?
3. Are there any other factors/considerations that I should be considering if I'm trying to determine the performance impact of switching to this new connection protocol compared to the old one?

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should also consider the latency impact of initiating the 3-way handshake every time a message is sent

Comment: Why are you doing this? You're going in the wrong direction. Everybody else has been furiously adding connection pooling to their applications and middleware layers for decades.

Answer (score 1):

Opening and closing a lot of TCP sessions may impact connection tracking firewalls and load balancers, causing them to slow down or even fail and reject the connection. Some, like the Linux iptables conntrack, have moderate default values for the number of tracked connections.

The program might run out of available local port numbers if it cycles messages too quickly. There is a TCP timeout before a socket can be considered "closed". There is often an operating system timer to clean up these closed connections. If too many sockets are opened too quickly, the operating system may not have had time to clean up.

The handshake adds about an extra 80 bytes to your bandwidth cost. The TCP connection close also involves FIN or RST packets, although these flags may be combined with the data packet.

Latency in an established TCP session might be a tiny bit higher if the Nagle algorithm is turned on for the message sender. Nagle causes the OS to wait for more data before sending a partially filled packet. The TCP session that is being closed will flush all data. The same effect can be had in the open session by disabling Nagle with the `TCP_NODELAY` flag.

Comment: The handshake takes three TCP segments of the minimum size 40 bytes, total 120, and the last one can be piggybacked on data.

Comment: @EJP: You've also got two F packets on the ends.

Comment: The handshake is still three segments. The closing FIN *segments* and their ACKS are another *four* segments, all of which can be piggybacked.

Comment: @EJP: Yep. Fixed it to 80 bytes.